# PathFinder_Exception Unable to include Model/Model/ using setModel

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

I'm trying to create a reference manually from one Model to another model, using the example given in http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/modeltable/reference. I'm using the following tables and models:

Person Table

- id: primary key
- name: char
- room_number: int
- email: char

User Table

- id: primary key
- person_id: foreign key to Person Table (id)
- password: char

The ATK4.2 classes are below:

### Person Model

```
class Model_Person extends Model_Table {
public $entity_code='person';

function init(){
    parent::init();
    $this->addField('name');
    $this->addField('roomnumber');
    $this->addField('email');
}
}
```

### User Model

## The 'user' table contains the password field.

```
class Model_User extends Model_Table {
public $entity_code='user';

function init(){
    parent::init();

    $field_ref = $this->add('Field_Reference', 'person_id');
    $field_ref->dereferenced_field = 'person_str';
    // add referenced Model
    $m = $this->add('Model_Person');
    $m->addField('name');
    // Link referenced model field name to this model field.
    $field_ref->setModel($m, 'name');


}
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error, where the Model_Person class is being added using the wrong path, Model/Model/Person.php

```
PathFinder_Exception

Unable to include Model/Model/Person.php

Additional information:

    type: php
    attempted_locations: Array ( [0] => /var/www/html/seqtrack/admin/lib/Model/Model/Person.php [1] => /var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/Model/Model/Person.php [2] => /var/www/html/seqtrack/admin/../lib/Model/Model/Person.php [3] => /var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/../atk4-addons/mvc/Model/Model/Person.php [4] => /var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/../atk4-addons/misc/lib/Model/Model/Person.php ) 

/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/BaseException.php:38
Stack trace:
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/BaseException.php   :38     PathFinder_Exception    PathFinder_Exception->collectBasicData(Null, 1, 0)
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/PathFinder.php  :213    PathFinder_Exception    PathFinder_Exception->__construct("Unable to include Model/Model/Person.php")
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/PathFinder.php  :131    PathFinder_Exception    PathFinder_Exception->__construct("php", "Model/Model/Person.php", Array(5))
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/PathFinder.php  :195    test_pathfinder PathFinder->locate("php", "Model/Model/Person.php", "path")
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/AbstractObject.php  :159    test_pathfinder PathFinder->loadClass("Model_Model_Person")
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/Field/Reference.php :89     test_mgr_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud_model_user_person_id    Field_Reference->add("Model_Model_Person")
/   :   test_mgr_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud_model_user_person_id    Field_Reference->calculateSubQuery(Object(Model_User), Object(DB_dsql_mysql), Object(Field_Expression))
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/Field/Expression.php    :44         Loggercall_user_func(Array(2), Object(Model_User), Object(DB_dsql_mysql), Object(Field_Expression))
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/Model/Table.php :169    test_mgr_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud_model_user_person_str   Field_Expression->updateSelectQuery(Object(DB_dsql_mysql))
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/Model/Table.php :327    test_mgr_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud_model_user  Model_User->selectQuery()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/CompleteLister.php  :104    test_mgr_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud_model_user  Model_User->rewind()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/Grid/Basic.php  :175    test_mgr_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud_grid    Grid->renderRows()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/CompleteLister.php  :118    test_mgr_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud_grid    Grid->renderRows()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/Grid/Advanced.php   :152    test_mgr_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud_grid    Grid->render()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/AbstractView.php    :214    test_mgr_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud_grid    Grid->render()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/AbstractView.php    :205    test_mgr_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud_grid    Grid->recursiveRender()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/AbstractView.php    :205    test_mgr_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud CRUD->recursiveRender()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/AbstractView.php    :205    test_mgr_tabs_view_htmlelement  View_HtmlElement->recursiveRender()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/AbstractView.php    :205    test_mgr_tabs   Tabs->recursiveRender()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/AbstractView.php    :205    test_mgr    page_mgr->recursiveRender()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/ApiWeb.php  :236    test    AdminFrontend->recursiveRender()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/ApiFrontend.php :123    test    AdminFrontend->execute()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/atk4/lib/ApiWeb.php  :226    test    AdminFrontend->execute()
/var/www/html/seqtrack/admin/index.php  :8  test    AdminFrontend->main()
```

A similar problem can be seen on the ATK DVD example web page:

http://example.agiletoolkit.org/examples/dvdrental/

```
PathFinder_Exception

Unable to include Model/Model/Customer.php

Additional information:

type: php
attempted_locations: Array ( [0] => /www/agiletoolkit.org/example/examples/dvdrental/lib/Model/Model/Customer.php [1] => /www/agiletoolkit.org/example/atk4/lib/Model/Model/Customer.php [2] => /www/agiletoolkit.org/example/atk4/../atk4-addons/mvc/Model/Model/Customer.php [3] => /www/agiletoolkit.org/example/atk4/../atk4-addons/misc/lib/Model/Model/Customer.php ) 

/www/agiletoolkit.org/example/atk4/lib/BaseException.php:38
Stack trace:
/www/agiletoolkit.org/example/atk4/lib/BaseException.php    :38     PathFinder_Exception    PathFinder_Exception->collectBasicData(Null, 1, 0)
/www/agiletoolkit.org/example/atk4/lib/PathFinder.php   :209    PathFinder_Exception    PathFinder_Exception->__construct("Unable to include Model/Model/Customer.php")
/www/agiletoolkit.org/example/atk4/lib/PathFinder.php   :134    PathFinder_Exception    PathFinder_Exception->__construct("php", "Model/Model/Customer.php", Array(4))
/www/agiletoolkit.org/example/atk4/lib/PathFinder.php   :195    Frontend_pathfinder PathFinder->locate("php", "Model/Model/Customer.php", "path")
/www/agiletoolkit.org/example/atk4/lib/AbstractObject.php   :158    Frontend_pathfinder PathFinder->loadClass("Model_Model_Customer")
/www/agiletoolkit.org/example/atk4/lib/AbstractController.php   :26     Frontend    Frontend->add("Model_Model_Customer")
/www/agiletoolkit.org/example/examples/dvdrental/lib/RentalAuth.php :5  Frontend_rentalauth RentalAuth->setModel("Model_Customer")
/www/agiletoolkit.org/example/atk4/lib/AbstractObject.php   :181    Frontend_rentalauth RentalAuth->init()
/www/agiletoolkit.org/example/examples/dvdrental/lib/Frontend.php   :21     Frontend    Frontend->add("RentalAuth")
/www/agiletoolkit.org/example/atk4/lib/ApiCLI.php   :48     Frontend    Frontend->init()
/www/agiletoolkit.org/example/atk4/lib/ApiWeb.php   :38     Frontend    Frontend->__construct(Null)
/www/agiletoolkit.org/example/examples/dvdrental/index.php  :3  Frontend    Frontend->__construct()
```

Cheers.

---

## Update

The code fragment needs to go into the User class, so it now looks like this:

```
class Model_User extends Model_Table {
public $entity_code='user';

function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->hasOne('Person');

    $field_ref = $this->getField('person')->rename('person_str');
    $this->getField('person_id')->dereferenced_field='person_str';

    // add referenced Model
    $m = $this->add('Model_Person');
    $m->addField('name');

    // Link referenced model field name to this model field.
    $field_ref->setModel($m, 'name');

}
}
```

The SQL produced is:

select `id`,`person_id`,(select `name` from `person` where `user`.`person_id` = `person`.`id` ) `person_str` from `user`

---

However the below class also produces the same SQL statemetn.

```
class Model_User extends Model_Table {
public $entity_code='user';

function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->hasOne('Person');

    $this->getField('person')->rename('person_str');

}
}
```

So I don't quite understand the function and need for the rest of the code:
$this->getField('person_id')->dereferenced_field='person_str';

```
    // add referenced Model
    $m = $this->add('Model_Person');
    $m->addField('name');

    // Link referenced model field name to this model field.
    $field_ref->setModel($m, 'name');
```

I hope we can get some further explanation on this, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, after some more playing, I just found that removing the lines after  $field_ref = $this->getField('person')->rename('person_str');
makes do difference to the SQL. Romaninsh are you able to elaborate on how the getField, addField and setModel work as the documentation is not clear on the workings of these methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this inside your person model

```
$this->hasOne('Person');
$this->getField('person')->rename('person_str');
$this->getField('person_id')->dereferenced_field='person_str';
```

otherwise "setmodel" is not working with pre-created objects.

Comment: Trying to set the dereferenced_field does not seem to work, so I added a bug at github with code changes to get it work as expected.